# Can I use Firebase simple login to access Twitter API?

Tags: firebase

It's easy to get the simple login working with Twitter, and that's a big bonus, but I was wondering whether it's possible to then take those authentication credentials and post a tweet, get a list of people they're following, generally use the full Twitter 1.1 API. I.e. can I get hold of the access token key and secret?

Thanks,
Dave.

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] While we don't currently expose both the Twitter access token key and secret in the response payload from Twitter login, I think that's a great idea. I'll add it to our backlog and follow-up here once it's been pushed live - likely within the next 2-3 weeks. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: To add to Rob's comment; if you're using simple login on iOS we do pass you the `ACAccount*` as a property of `FAUser` when signing in. You can then use this to kick off regular iOS `SLRequest`s (More details here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Simple Login JavaScript client now returns both the Twitter access token and access token secret in the response payload from Twitter authentication.

You can access each of these via the `user` object, under the attributes `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` as shown below:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://<MY-FIREBASE-NAME>.firebaseIO.com');
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
  if (user) {
    var accessToken = user.accessToken,
        accessTokenSecret = user.accessTokenSecret;
  }
});

...

// Sample jQuery click event.
$myButton.on('click', function(event) {
  authClient.login('twitter');
});
```

Comment: how do you use the accessToken and accessTokenSecret in the twitter 1.1 api?

Comment: @stukennedy do you figure out how to use accessToken and secret with the twitter 1.1 api ?